# Avoid Ring Buffer Overflow in Reader-Writer C Program

Tags: c, multithreading, buffer

I have a multithread C program (as below)that multiple writers add elements to a shared ring buffer and a single reader read elements from the buffer. The main problem is buffer overflow! Is it possible to avoid buffer overflow when number of elements exceeds buffer size?

Writer Code:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_ptr->mutex);

if((buffer_ptr->tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE == buffer_ptr->head)
pthread_cond_wait( &buffer_ptr->cond_write, &buffer_ptr->mutex );

pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_ptr->mutex);

pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_ptr->mutex);

if ((buffer_ptr->tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE != buffer_ptr->head)
{

memmove(buffer_ptr->chunk[buffer_ptr->tail], chunk, chunk_size);    //Write chunk into buffer
buffer_ptr->chunk[buffer_ptr->tail][chunk_size] = '\0';

buffer_ptr->chunk_size[buffer_ptr->tail] = chunk_size;      //Write chunk size into buffer

buffer_ptr->tail = (buffer_ptr->tail + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;

}

pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_ptr->cond_write);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_ptr->mutex);
```

Reader Code:

```
while (TRUE)
        {

        if (buffer_ptr->tail != buffer_ptr->head)
            {
        readchunk = TRUE;

        chunksize = buffer_ptr->chunk_size[buffer_ptr->head];       //Read chunk size from buffer

        memmove(chunk, buffer_ptr->chunk[buffer_ptr->head], chunksize);     //Read chunk from buffer
        chunk[chunksize] = '\0';

            buffer_ptr->head = (buffer_ptr->head + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;

            }
}
```

Comment: You should use a counting semaphore.